# Switching to another datasource (on the fly)

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want two different data-sources in my application (one is for testing)

How can I tell to a Model what data-source to use?

And is it also also possible to do that on the fly in a Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ConnectionManager::alias()`:

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_alias

Fore example this will make all tables that require the `default` connection to use `custom:

```
ConnectionManager::alias('custom', 'default');
```